# Underscores in numeric literals in scala

Tags: scala, literals

Apparently scala does not support the jdk7 and later underscores in numeric literals?

I am using jdk 8

```
scala> System.getProperty("java.version")
res0: String = 1.8.0_40
```

Here we try to use a jdk7 (and later) numeric literal:

```
scala> val x = 1_000_000
<console>:1: error: Invalid literal number
       val x = 1_000_000
               ^
```

Is there a scala language option for this?

Comment: This is a `javac` thing. There is no reason to think that `scalac` would support it. Very little Java syntax is valid Scala.

Comment: There was [a long \[scala-debate\] thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/4-CE9Lpf6CM/UJrhS9cyYcgJ) about this just last week. Short answer: no, there's not, but this may be available in Scala some day, and in the meantime there are a number of ways to get something similar without much syntactic noise.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Scala is actually pretty close to Java in terms of syntax for literals, so the expectation that it would support underscores here isn't unreasonable.

Comment: @TravisBrown Feel free to make an answer out of your comment and I will award

Comment: @TravisBrown is on a diet of one answer a day, already reached satiety. Which reminds me, I have to go catch up on Travis Brown answers. It would be easier if Travis were on Hulu. I'd never miss an episode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that starting `Scala 2.13`, underscore is accepted as a numeric literal separator:

```
val x = 1_000_000
// x: Int = 1000000
val pi = 3_14e-0_2
// pi: Double = 3.14
```

Comment: @javadba, yes, I know..., you're using Scala on Spark and won't be able to use Scala 2.13 before an eternity!

Comment: ya i've used scala almost every day and have never touched 2.12 ..  2.13 will be another 3-5 years out

Answer (score 17):

In the Scala land you may have seen things like:

```
s"My name is $firstName"
```

and

```
sql"select id, name from members where id = ${id}"
```

There's no reason not to have:

```
i"1 000 000"
```

or even:

```
animal"Dog" // checks that Dog is on the list of animal words
```

There is no `i` string interpolation built in to the Scala library however you can use:

```
implicit class IntContext(val sc: StringContext) {
  def i(args: Any*): Int = {
    val orig = sc.s(args: _*)
    orig.replace(" ", "").toInt
  }
}

i"1 000 000" // res0: Int = 1000000
```

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering specificallly about the builtin compiler support - which one of the comments to the OP addressed quite well.

Comment: There is no built in support. Have to write out the number without any gap or use the approach I've explained here if performance isn't a concern.

Comment: I appreciate your approach but I do not need implicits: if there were no language support then so be it.  It appears it were undecided for future support or not.

Comment: Don't use it :) Don't worry :) It's one approach I've seen used for similar validation/parsing requirement. Doesn't mean I, you or anyone else have to use it. I'm not sure about the underscore with Java to be honest. Int(100,000,000) for example seems better.

Comment: +1 because this is the canonical answer for now. Unless it duplicates a canonical answer. I think this was the first example in retronym's macrocosm. No, that was showTree; binary literals came a week later.

Answer (score -1):

You can now write lengthy numeric literals that have a great readability score many thanks to the update done in Java 7. Read More on Adeva's blog https://adevait.com/java/5-best-and-worst-practices-in-java-coding

Before using Underscore:

```
int minUploadSize = 05437326;
long debitBalance = 5000000000000000L;
float pi = 3.141592653589F;
```

After making use of Underscore:

```
int minUploadSize = 05_437_326;
long debitBalance = 5_000_000_000_000_000L;
float pi = 3.141_592_653_589F;
```

The above-written declarations in Java show the importance of using underscores in numeric literals to improve the readability of codes. When you compare the two declarations above, you would be able to deduce that the one with included underscores is more readable compared to the other one.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer to the one by @XavierGuihot (from 2019)